# Remote Script Execution using Fabric

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I want to create a fabfile:

1. To execute a script on remote server ( need to first **ssh** with my userid and pass and then **"sudo su - $accuser"**) that actually starts tomcat instances.
2. After the string "Started" comes when first tomcat instance gets executed, the control passes to the next line of code to start second instance.

Comment: You should take a look at this [guide on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1013 there are some options